# json string values missing quotes python script

Tags: python, json, database

I have data in .json file but they are invalid because string values are missing quotes.
I have tried to create script in python but it did not work at all. I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.
This is the input file:

```
{
  "xmusil4_knihy":{
    "knihy_id": 2,
    "isbn": ISBN 80-86497-24-0,
    "nazev": Oracle9i,
    "pocet_stran": 480,
    "rok_vydani": 2002,
    "misto_vydani": Praha,
    "nakladatel": SoftPress,
    "vydani": 1,
    "druhy_id": 1,
    "jazyky_id": 2,
    "autor": Abbey, Michael -- Corey, Michael
  }
  "xmusil4_knihy":{
    "knihy_id": 4,
    "isbn": ISBN 1-85032-167-1,
    "nazev": An Introduction to Neural Computing,
    "pocet_stran": 21,
    "rok_vydani": 1995,
    "misto_vydani": London,
    "nakladatel": International Thomson Computer Press,
    "vydani": 2,
    "druhy_id": 1,
    "jazyky_id": 2,
    "autor": Aleksander, Igor -- Morton, Helen
  }
...
```

And this is expected output:

```
{
  "xmusil4_knihy":{
    "knihy_id": 2,
    "isbn": "ISBN 80-86497-24-0",
    "nazev": "Oracle9i",
    "pocet_stran": 480,
    "rok_vydani": 2002,
    "misto_vydani": "Praha",
    "nakladatel": "SoftPress",
    "vydani": 1,
    "druhy_id": 1,
    "jazyky_id": 2,
    "autor": "Abbey, Michael -- Corey, Michael"
  }
  "xmusil4_knihy":{
    "knihy_id": 4,
    "isbn": "ISBN 1-85032-167-1",
    "nazev": "An Introduction to Neural Computing",
    "pocet_stran": 21,
    "rok_vydani": 1995,
    "misto_vydani": "London",
    "nakladatel": "International Thomson Computer Press",
    "vydani": 2,
    "druhy_id": 1,
    "jazyky_id": 2,
    "autor": "Aleksander, Igor -- Morton, Helen"
  }
```

I tried using json library in python.

Comment: Realistically, you don't fix this; whoever is producing this file needs to produce valid JSON.

Comment: This is a school project, and fixing the invalid data is part of the task.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no `"` will appear except in a key?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed. They are missing in every string value.

Comment: what about the closing `}`...  was this an intended error ?

Comment: your expected output has the same key (`xmusil4_knihy`) twice

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot more issues in the JSON file than I thought. I fixed it with a highly complex Python script. The script is not universal so there is no point in posting it.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).